# Rotating an SVG figure around its center in a cross-browser way (including IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I am trying to have an SVG figure rotate around its center. For this purpose I am calculating the rotation center, and scaling it according to `viewBox`. It works like a charm in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but despite all my efforts, I couldn't make it work in Internet Explorer. I have tried changing the `preserveAspectRatio`, checking what's wrong with my values, but couldn't figure it out ... Any idea?

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
</head>
<body>
<svg version="1.1" id="sketch" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1332 1080" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1332 1080;" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
 <g id="wheel1">
  <g>
   <path class="st8" d="M258.4,149c-123.7,0-224,100.3-224,224s100.3,224,224,224s224-100.3,224-224S382.1,149,258.4,149z M258.9,533
    c-88.4,0-160-71.6-160-160s71.6-160,160-160s160,71.6,160,160S347.2,533,258.9,533z"/>
   <g>
    <polyline class="st9" points="258.5,149 282,181 258.5,213    "/>
   </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<script type="text/javascript">
var svg = document.getElementById('sketch')
  var wheel = document.getElementById('wheel1')

  var svgBBox = svg.getBoundingClientRect()
  var wheelBBox = wheel.getBoundingClientRect()

  // calculate the rotation center of the wheel
  var cx = (wheelBBox.left - svgBBox.left) + wheelBBox.width / 2
  var cy = (wheelBBox.top - svgBBox.top) + wheelBBox.height / 2

  // Calculate the ratio for scaling measurments according to viewBox / viewport
  var viewBox = svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ').map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 10) })
  var ratioX = viewBox[2] / svgBBox.width
  var ratioY = viewBox[3] / svgBBox.height

var t0 = Date.now()

// Rotate loop
  setInterval(function() {
var delta = (Date.now() - t0)
wheel.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + delta * 0.05 + ', ' + (cx * ratioX) + ', ' + (cy * ratioY) + ')')
  }, 10)
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  .st9 { fill: yellow; }
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use getBBox() instead of getBoundingClientRect(). The coordinates  of getBBox() already relative to the viewBox. You can use these values directly independent of any viewBox.

Not sure if this fixes IE...

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('sketch')
var wheel = document.getElementById('wheel1')
var wheelBBox = wheel.getBBox()

  // calculate the rotation center of the wheel
  var cx = wheelBBox.x + wheelBBox.width / 2
  var cy = wheelBBox.y + + wheelBBox.height / 2

var t0 = Date.now()

// Rotate loop
  setInterval(function() {
var delta = (Date.now() - t0)
wheel.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + delta * 0.05 + ', ' + cx + ', ' + cy + ')')
  }, 10)
```

```css
.st9 { fill: yellow; }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="sketch" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1332 1080" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1332 1080;" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
 <g id="wheel1">
  <g>
   <path class="st8" d="M258.4,149c-123.7,0-224,100.3-224,224s100.3,224,224,224s224-100.3,224-224S382.1,149,258.4,149z M258.9,533
    c-88.4,0-160-71.6-160-160s71.6-160,160-160s160,71.6,160,160S347.2,533,258.9,533z"/>
   <g>
    <polyline class="st9" points="258.5,149 282,181 258.5,213    "/>
   </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```